# Unable to reload Nginx context

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am newbie to Nginx and adding upstream configuration dynamically through a java program, after that I am trying to reload the context and getting the below error. I tried to reload context on command prompt even and getting sane error over there. I opened the command prompt using admin rights.

```
C:\nginx-1.16.1>nginx -s reload
nginx: [error] OpenEvent("Global\ngx_reload_6512") failed (5: Access is denied)
```

Please share if some one have already come across this problem and found some solution.

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same issue, and it's hard to find an answer. Nginx seems to be terrible choice on windows, I'll probably be changing it to apache